# Find elisp origin of warning

Tags: debugging

I ran a command and received a warning in the minibuffer.

The exact warning was `comint-completion-at-point failed to return valid completion data`, after I autocompleted a command in `shell-mode`.

How can I determine the elisp origin of the warning?

Comment: Have a look at the manual on [Debugging Lisp Programs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugging.html#Debugging).

Comment: `C-h f comint-completion-at-point`, then click the file name to see the source code. Look for that error message. (You can also grep for the error msg in the Lisp sources, to find it.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As pointed out in the other answer you'll find [the fine manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugging.html#Debugging) useful for all the debug tools it has. For you specific problem I'd consider:

```
(setq debug-on-message "comint-completion-at-point failed to return valid completion data")
```

As the help text states:

```
If non-nil, debug if a message matching this regexp is displayed.
```

From this you should get a backtrace when the failure hits. You can then instrument the functions in question with *C-u C-M-x* and step through the failure next time it occurs for more information.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Thank you. I think you have an extra quote in your first line, where you combine `setq` and `'debug-on-message`. Changing it to `setq debug-on-message` or `set 'debug-on-message` fixed it for me.

Comment: @MatthewPiziak: thanks - overzealous quoting fixed.

Comment: This is so much better than zgrepping the Emacs compressed sources! Only downside of this is that the problematic condition must occur before one can debug it.

Comment: That doesn't appear to work (at least for `Warning (emacs)` messages) — Perhaps because these are generated from a place in the C code where the debugger won't work?

Comment: @DomQ usually these messages come from `(warn MESSAGE &rest ARGS)` call somewhere in the elisp source so I would just grep for such a call first. Another possible scenario is that `warn` is called when a special error type `user-error` happens. This error type does not trigger the debugger (even with `toggle-debug-on-error` enabled) because it is in the `debug-ignored-errors` list. Removing `user-error` from `debug-ignored-errors` will enter debug mode at the point when warnings are issued. Good luck with debugging:)