# "Unable to activate package" when starting Emacs

Tags: package, start-up, warning

I get the following message when starting Emacs:

```
Warning (emacs): Unable to activate package `elpy'.
Required package `highlight-indentation-0.5.0' is unavailable
Warning (emacs): Unable to activate package `elpy'.
Required package `highlight-indentation-0.5.0' is unavailable
Warning (emacs): Unable to activate package `elpy'.
Required package `highlight-indentation-0.5.0' is unavailable
```

I then found this Q&A: 
[Find elisp origin of warning](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/find-elisp-origin-of-warning)

So I followed the accepted answer and added the following to the top of my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq debug-on-message "Unable to activate package `elpy'.")
```

and then restarted Emacs, but nothing happened. Was I supposed to fall into the debugger?

How can I find what specific line in my `.emacs` file trigger the warning?

Comment: This is happening during package activation, so it's not your init file's fault. Just install the missing package.

Comment: Thanks @Malarba. I have uninstalled these packages precisely because they are [giving me problems](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/435), so what I want to do is find out what is loading them.

Comment: Elpy is loading it. As explained in the warning and in the (elpy) issue you linked. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening during package activation, so it's not your init file's fault.

## What's happening

The warning is telling you everything you need to know. `elpy` needs to load `highlight-indentation`, but the package's not installed.

## What to do

Either

- install the missing package
- or delete `elpy`.

Comment: Is it possible to check if the specific package failed to be activated then install it automatically so I don't need to install it manually?